# Listener em um botão dentro de uma notificação

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Estou fazendo um app que toca uma stream de rádio, e quando começa a tocar, crio uma notificação customizada com 2 botões, um para dar pause/play e outra pra remover a notificação e parar a stream, porém não obtive sucesso e os botões não fazem nada, dei uma lida a respeito de PendingIntent e BroadcastReceiver mas sem sucesso, alguém consegue me ajudar?

Os códigos dos botões:

```
    Intent it = new Intent(MyService.this,MainActivity.class);
    it.setAction("tocando");
    it.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyService.this, 0, it, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    builder.setContentIntent(pi);
    Intent itt = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyBroadcast.class);
    itt.putExtra("comand", "pause");
    PendingIntent pitt = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),23424324, itt, 0);
    RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notificacao);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.pause, pitt);
    builder.setContent(view);
    Notification not = builder.build();
```

Comment: Por acaso gera algum erro no LogCat ? Se sim, coloque seus códigos dos botões e o erro do LogCat também.

Comment: Não gera nada :( se fosse possível eu queria um exemplo pq tá difícil

Comment: Essa parte não é tão a minha área, pois faz tempo que não mexo no *Android*, mas faz assim, poste o código dos botões porque com eles aqui fica mais fácil alguém te ajudar e aumenta a chance de uma resposta que esclareça sua dúvida. :)

Comment: Ninguem...?? :(